# ¿cómo agregar un nuevo elemento a un archivo.csv e interactuar con esté, sin cerrar la ejecución del programa en ningún momento?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Estoy creando un gestor de tareas en Python con la librería Pandas, en el cual una de las opciones que tiene es, crear una nueva tarea, al crear está nueva tarea también la guarda en un archivo.csv:

```
def crear_tarea(self):
        crear_titulo = input("ingrese un titulo a su tarea: ")
        crear_descripcion = input("ingrese una descripcion a su tarea: \n")
        # si quiero colocar fechas o horas en mi data frame debo usar pd.to_datatime() y no str
        # Y seleccionar el formato deseado
        convertir_a_fecha = pd.to_datetime(input("ingrese una fecha de creación a su tarea con el formato DD/MM/AAAA: "), format="%d/%m/%Y", dayfirst=True)
        convertir_a_fecha_vencimiento = pd.to_datetime(input("ingrese una fecha de vencimiento a su tarea con el formato DD/MM/AAAA: "),  format="%d/%m/%Y", dayfirst=True)
        nueva_tarea = Tarea(crear_titulo, crear_descripcion, convertir_a_fecha, convertir_a_fecha_vencimiento)
        self.tareas.append(nueva_tarea)
        self.guardar_tarea(nueva_tarea)
        return nueva_tarea

def guardar_tarea(self, tarea_a_guardar):
    df_aux = pd.DataFrame({
        "titulo" : [tarea_a_guardar.titulo],
        "descripción" : [tarea_a_guardar.descripcion],
        "fecha de creación" : [tarea_a_guardar.fecha_creacion],
        "fecha de vencimiento" : [tarea_a_guardar.fecha_vencimiento],
        "completada" : [tarea_a_guardar.completada]
    })

    df_aux.to_csv("registro_tareas.csv", mode = "a", header = False, index = False, date_format = '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Y luego de ejecutarse la tarea seleccionada, vuelve al menú de inicio:

```
class AplicacionGestorTareas:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista_tareas = ListaDeTareas()
        self.df = pd.read_csv("registro_tareas.csv")

    def iniciar_aplicación(self):
        self.lista_tareas.cargar_tarea()
        opcion = 0
        while opcion != "0":
            print("### GESTOR DE TAREAS ###")
            print("1. Ver todas las tareas")
            print("2. Ver tareas pendientes")
            print("3. Ver tareas completadas")
            print("4. crear nueva tarea")
            print("5. marcar tarea como completada")
            print("6. Editar tarea existente")
            print("7. Eliminar tarea existente")
            print("8. Filtrar tareas por fecha de creación")
            print("0. Salir")

            opcion = input("Ingrese el numero de la opcion deseada: ") 
            
            match opcion:
                case "1":
                    self.lista_tareas.mostrara_todas_las_tareas()
                case "2":
                    self.lista_tareas.mostrar_tareas_pendientes()
                case "3":
                    self.lista_tareas.mostrar_tareas_completadas()
                case "4":
                    self.lista_tareas.crear_tarea()
                case "5":
                    tarea_titulo_input = input("coloque el titulo de la tarea que desea marcar como compleada: ")
                    df_aux = self.lista_tareas.marcar_como_completada(tarea_titulo_input)
                    df_aux.to_csv("registro_tareas.csv", index = False)
                case "6":
                    tarea_titulo_input = input("coloque el titulo de la tarea que desea editar: ")
                    nuevo_titulo = input("coloque el nuevo titulo de la tarea: \n")
                    nueva_descripcion = input("coloque la nueva descripcion de la tarea: \n")
                    df_aux = self.lista_tareas.editar_tarea(tarea_titulo_input ,nuevo_titulo, nueva_descripcion)
                    df_aux.to_csv("registro_tareas.csv", index = False)
                case "7":
                    titulo_tarea = input("coloque el titulo de la tarea que desea eliminar: ")
                    df_aux = self.lista_tareas.eliminar_tarea(titulo_tarea) 
                    df_aux[0].to_csv("registro_tareas.csv", index = False)
                case "8":
                    fecha = input("ingrese la fecha de creación de la tarea: ")
                    self.lista_tareas.buscar_tarea_por_fecha(fecha)
                case "0":
                    pass
    




app = AplicacionGestorTareas()
app.iniciar_aplicación()
```

El problema es que cuando intento interactuar con esa tarea recién creada no pasa nada, por ejemplo eliminándola con la opción 7 del menú:

```
def eliminar_tarea(self, titulo_tarea):
        for index, row in self.df.iterrows():
            if row["titulo"] == titulo_tarea:
                nuevo_df = self.df.drop(index, axis=0, inplace = True) # estoy eliminando la tarea dada del df original
                titulo_encontrado = True
                break
            else:
                titulo_encontrado = False

        if titulo_encontrado == True:
            print("- Tarea eliminada")
            return self.df, nuevo_df  # recordar que con un mismo return podemos retornar multiples elementos
        else:                         # y seran devueltos en una tupla
            print(f"- No se encontro una tarea con el titulo: {titulo_tarea}")
            return self.df,
```

El archivo.csv:

```
titulo,descripción,fecha de creación,fecha de vencimiento,completada
c,w,12/06/2023,12/06/2024,False
d,w,12/06/2023,12/06/2024,False
t,e,12/06/2024,12/06/2024,False
u,uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu,12/06/2024,12/06/2024,False
g,gggggggg,12/06/2024,12/06/2024,False
```

supongamos que yo creé una tarea con el titulo "g" y justo después yo quiero eliminar esta tarea, el problema es que el `for` de la función `eliminar_tarea` no llega hasta la tarea g, si no que recorre hasta la tarea con el titulo "u". Es como si la tarea g no estuviera en el `archivo.scv`, por lo tanto la función ejecuta las siguientes líneas de código:

```
print(f"- No se encontro una tarea con el titulo: {titulo_tarea}")
            return self.df,
```

Y después de ejecutar el `return self.df,` la tarea g ya no aparece en el archivo.csv pero esto ocurre porque devolvió el df no porque se halla eliminado la tarea (al debugear el  programa esto es más evidente)

Al crear la tarea g, cerrar el programa con la opción "0" y después volver a ejecutar el programa e intentar eliminar la tarea g, hay si funciona y se elimina la tarea g del archivo.csv

Pareciera que el programa trabaja con una versión del archivo.csv en la que todavía no se ha creado la tarea

y yo me pregunto: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear y eliminar una tarea en la misma ejecución del programa?

Comment: Cuando añades tareas no actualizas `self.df`, la tarea se agrega  al csv pero `self.df` es el que cargaste al iniciar la app...

Comment: puedo cargarlo devuelta después de haber creado la tarea?

Comment: Claro, puedes llamar a read_csv de nuevo como haces en el inicializador, o modificar self.df directamente añadiendo la fila correspondiente. No obstante, lo normal seria tener los datos en memoria (las tareas) sin duplicar, por ejemplo en self.lista_tareas y guardar en el archivo solo cuando sea necesario a traves de pandas o incluso con el modulo csv de Python (si solo usas pandas para generar y leer el csv quizas sea un poco excesivo para algo tan simple, aunque no quiere decir que este mal). Ahora parece que los datos los tienes tanto en lista_tareas como en df ademas del archivo csv.

Comment: guardo las tareas en el archivo.csv para que no se borren cuando cierro el programa

Comment: Si eso es normal, a lo que me refiero  sobre duplicar los datos en memoria es a que guardas aparentemente (no esta todo el codigo) las tareas tanto en `self.lista_tareas` como en `self.df`.